# Azure blob to Azure SQL Database: Cannot bulk load because the file "xxxx.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.)

Tags: sql, database, azure, blob, bulkinsert

I am trying to bulk load in azure sql database some data in an azure blob storage.
The file content is:

```
 customer,age,gender
'C1093826151','4','M'
'C352968107','2','M'
'C2054744914','4','F'
```

the file is in a container called **silver**.
in the silver container I have the File1.fmt which content is:

```
14.0  
3
1       SQLCHAR       0       7       ","      1     customer       ""  
2       SQLCHAR       0       100     ","      2     age            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
3       SQLCHAR       0       100     "\r\n"   3     gender         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

I have the extra line add the end of the fmt file.

I have created a SAS token will all enabled and allowed like the screenshot below:
[image]

The firewall rules on datalake are as the picture below:

[image]

Below are my sql scripts (I removed the ? at the beginning of the SAS token, as my silver container is public, I  know I should need the SAS token):

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'safepassword';
go
DROP EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureInvoices

DROP DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL UploadInvoices

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL UploadInvoices
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'sv=2019-12-12**********************************88%3D'; -- dl

--DROP EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureInvoices

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureInvoices
    WITH (
        TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
        LOCATION = 'https://mydatalake.blob.core.windows.net/silver',
        CREDENTIAL = UploadInvoices
    );
```

Landing table:

```
CREATE TABLE [ext].[customer](
    [customer_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [customer] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [age] [int] NOT NULL,
    [gender] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

and these are the ways I tried to load the file into the sql database:

```
-- 1
    SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'bs140513_032310-demo.csv',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices',
   FORMAT = 'CSV',
   FORMATFILE='File1.fmt',
   FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices'
   ) AS DataFile;   
-- 2    
    go
    SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'bs140513_032310-demo.csv',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices',
   SINGLE_CLOB) AS DataFile;
   go
-- 3
BULK INSERT ext.customer
FROM 'bs140513_032310-demo.csv'
WITH (
DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices', FORMAT = 'CSV' );
```

They all give the same error:

```
Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot bulk load because the file "bs140513_032310-demo.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).
```

I have tried for 3 days and I am lost. Thanks for your help
NB:

While being disconnected, it can access the files:

*

- https://mydatalake.blob.core.windows.net/silver/File1.fmt
  https://mydatalake.blob.core.windows.net/silver/bs140513_032310-demo.csv

- 

mydatalake is fake, but I can access with the real name

Comment: see if the file is open in any spredsheet application. Many times it has happened to me that I saved an excel as csv and tried to upload it in sql but failed because it was still open in spread sheet application

Comment: Thanks Codeek, all file editors are closed and the file is in Azure Data Lake container

Comment: You can try to delete `bs140513_032310-demo.csv`, it will show the file doesn't exist. This error is confirmed on the side, SQL engine can access the file.

Comment: Hi Joseph, i am able to download the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this error message is misleading.
I've created a same test as you, and encountered the same error.
But after I edited the `bs140513_032310-demo.csv` and  `File1.fmt`, it works well.

1. I changed the `bs140513_032310-demo.csv` like this:
   [image]
2. I changed the `File1.fmt` like this, I changed the **cutomer column** length from 7 to 100 and **age column** length from 100 to 7 :

```
14.0  
3
1       SQLCHAR       0       100       ","      1     customer       ""
2       SQLCHAR       0       7         ","      2     age            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR       0       100       "\r\n"   3     gender         ""
```

3. I use the following statement to query:

```
   SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'bs140513_032310-demo.csv',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices',
   FORMAT = 'CSV',
   FORMATFILE='File1.fmt',
   FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices'
   ) AS DataFile;
```

The result shows:
[image]

4. Don't **BULK INSERT** into your real tables directly.

- I would always insert into a staging table ext.customer_Staging (without the IDENTITY column) from the CSV file
- possibly edit / clean up / manipulate your imported data
- and then copy the data across to the real table with a T-SQL statement like:

```sql
INSERT into  ext.customer_Staging with (TABLOCK) (customer, age, gender)
   SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'bs140513_032310-demo.csv',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices',
   FORMAT = 'CSV',
   FORMATFILE='File1.fmt',
   FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices'
   ) AS DataFile;
   go

INSERT INTO ext.customer(Name, Address) 
   SELECT customer, age, gender
   FROM ext.customer_Staging
```