# Issue with ERRORFILE when BULK INSERTing from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, bulkinsert

I am trying to bulk insert a lot of CSV files from Azure Blob Storage into my Azure SQL database.

Here's how I am trying to achieve this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID('[sqldb1].[dbo].[TABLE_A_RAW]'))
    DROP TABLE [sqldb1].[dbo].[TABLE_A_RAW];
    
CREATE TABLE [sqldb1].[dbo].[TABLE_A_RAW]
(
        [COL1] varchar(60),
        [COL2] varchar(60),
        [COL3] varchar(60),
        [COL4] varchar(60),
        [COL5] varchar(60)
);
        
BULK INSERT [sqldb1].[dbo].[TABLE_A_RAW]
FROM 'TABLE_A.CSV'
WITH
    (
        DATA_SOURCE = 'myazureblobstoragecontainer',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        ERRORFILE = 'load_errors_TABLE_A',
        ERRORFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'myazureblobstoragecontainer',
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = '0xE29691',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
    )
GO
    
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID('[sqldb1].[dbo].[TABLE_B_RAW]'))
    DROP TABLE [sqldb1].[dbo].[TABLE_B_RAW];
    
CREATE TABLE [sqldb1].[dbo].[TABLE_B_RAW]
(
        [COL1] varchar(60),
        [COL2] varchar(60),
        [COL3] varchar(60),
        [COL4] varchar(60),
        [COL5] varchar(60),
        [COL6] varchar(60),
        [COL7] varchar(60),
        [COL8] varchar(60),
        [COL9] varchar(60)
);
        
BULK INSERT [sqldb1].[dbo].[TABLE_B_RAW]
FROM 'TABLE_B.CSV'
WITH
    (
        DATA_SOURCE = 'myazureblobstoragecontainer',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        ERRORFILE = 'load_errors_TABLE_B',
        ERRORFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'myazureblobstoragecontainer',
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = '0xE29691',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
    )
GO
```

The code above was developed when I worked on an almost identical project (with identical deployment) and it worked without any issues. When I tried to run the code above for my current project, the error log files get created and so do the tables (as expected) but they are all empty and I get these errors:

> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
> Cannot bulk load because the file "load_errors_TABLE_A" could not be opened. Operating system error code 80(The file exists.).
>
> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
> Cannot bulk load because the file "load_errors_TABLE_A.Error.Txt" could not be opened. Operating system error code 80(The file exists.).
>
> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 50
> Cannot bulk load because the file "load_errors_TABLE_B" could not be opened. Operating system error code 80(The file exists.).
>
> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 50
> Cannot bulk load because the file "load_errors_TABLE_B.Error.Txt" could not be opened. Operating system error code 80(The file exists.).

The error files are only created when I run the code above, meaning that they don't exist prior to running the code above as the error messages seem to indicate. When I comment-out the lines that say `ERRORFILE` and `ERRORFILE_DATA_SOURCE` (i.e.`ERRORFILE = 'load_errors_TABLE_A',`, `ERRORFILE = 'load_errors_TABLE_B',`, and `ERRORFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'myazureblobstoragecontainer',`) and run the script again, then the bulk insert finishes without any errors (but the error files don't end up being created, obviously).

I want to `BULK INSERT` WITH `ERRORFILE`s so that I can track any truncations that occur during the operation, like I did in my previous project. I tried looking for similar posts but they all seem to mostly relate to local `BULK INSERT` operations where the error log files is also created/stored locally. The deployment for the previous project and this one are almost identical, as I mentioned above - They are both running SQL Server 2014 (12.0.2000.8) and I have read/write access to both the Azure DB and Blob Storage account + container.

Comment: Do your csv files have headers? Does this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64835887/azure-blob-to-azure-sql-database-cannot-bulk-load-because-the-file-xxxx-csv-c/64853761#64853761) help you？

Comment: Yes, they do, but I highly doubt the issues are from the CSV files themsleves since they get bulk inserted when I comment-out the code creating the error log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit ended up being the permissions, as @joseph-xu suggested in his answer below.

Current Project:

[image: Screenshot of Permissions for current project from MS Azure Storage Explorer]

Old Project:

[image: Screenshot of Permissions for old project from MS Azure Storage Explorer]

The SAS key for the Blob Storage I was using for this project was missing `DELETE` and `DELETE VERSION` permissions, which is necessary if you want to include `ERRORFILE` and `ERRORFILE_DATA_SOURCE` in your `BULK INSERT` statement. As far as I am aware, this is not mentioned in Microsoft's documentation (and the error message doesn't hint at this being the issue either).

I simply created a new SAS key with ALL permissions, used that to create a new `DATABASE SCOPED CREDNETIAL` and `EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE`, and ran my code again and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your SAS key has not expired, right? And please check the **Allowed permissions**.
   [image]
2. Did you delete the **question mark** when you create the SECRET?

```sql
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL UploadInvoices
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'sv=2019-12-12******2FspTCY%3D'
```

I've tried the following test, it works well.  My csv file has no header.

```sql
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '***';
go

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL UploadInvoices
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'sv=2019-12-12&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp******%2FspTCY%3D'; -- dl


CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureInvoices
    WITH (
        TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
        LOCATION = 'https://***.blob.core.windows.net/<container_name>',
        CREDENTIAL = UploadInvoices
    );

BULK INSERT production.customer
FROM 'bs140513_032310-demo.csv'
WITH
    (
        DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        ERRORFILE = 'load_errors_TABLE_B',
        ERRORFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices',
        FIRSTROW = 2
    )
GO
```