# Access Azure Blob Storage via Azure SQL Database through Managed Identity

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am trying to connect to Azure Blob storage via Azure SQK database through Managed Identity based on the below set of steps:

1. Assigned an Identity to the Server
2. Gave access to the Server on Blob storage as contributor
3. Executed the below queries

   Create Master Key

   ```
    CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL MSI WITH IDENTITY = 'Managed Service Identity';


        CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [BlobStorage] WITH
    (  
        TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
        LOCATION = 'https://<<blobnm>>.blob.core.windows.net/<<containerNm>>',
        CREDENTIAL = MSI
    )

    create table test
    (
    c1 varchar(5),
    c2 varchar(4)
    )

    BULK INSERT test from 'poly.csv' WITH ( DATA_SOURCE = 'BlobStorage',FORMAT='csv',FIRSTROW = 2 );
   ```

But I am getting the below error :

`Cannot bulk load because the file "msi/poly.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 86(The specified network password is not correct.)`

So can anyone tell me what I am missing out ?

Comment: Is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64835887/azure-blob-to-azure-sql-database-cannot-bulk-load-because-the-file-xxxx-csv-c/64853761#64853761) helpful for you? There are many reasons for this error.

Comment: I've searched for several days but not found any explanation for 'Managed Service Identity' in Azure SQL. I think we can change to using SAS key.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a mistake in your command that you use to create the CREDENTIALS in SQL. It has to be

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL ServiceIdentity WITH IDENTITY = 'Managed Identity';
```

and not `'Managed Service Identity'`

Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-credential-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

The database scoped credential of "Managed Service Identity" is fine. But the RBAC permission on the storage account, needs to be "Storage Blob Data Contributor", not "Contributor"

Answer (score -1):

There are many reasons for this error. I have listed some reasons as follows:

1. Check whether the SAS key has expired? And please check the **Allowed permissions**.
   [image]
2. Did you delete the **question mark** when you create the SECRET?

```sql
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL UploadInvoices
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'sv=2019-12-12******2FspTCY%3D'
```

I also tried the following test, it works well.  My csv file has **no headers**.

```sql
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '***';
go

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL UploadInvoices
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'sv=2019-12-12&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp******%2FspTCY%3D'; -- dl


CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureInvoices
    WITH (
        TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
        LOCATION = 'https://***.blob.core.windows.net/<container_name>',
        CREDENTIAL = UploadInvoices
    );

BULK INSERT production.customer
FROM 'bs140513_032310-demo.csv'
WITH
    (
        DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        ERRORFILE = 'load_errors_TABLE_B',
        ERRORFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices',
        FIRSTROW = 2
    )
GO
```

Comment: Hey,
The Database scoped credential here is Managed service Identity which has entire access on the Blob storage via RBAC and no where am I using SAS token.

Comment: Ok，can you show us some example data of your csv file? Do your csv file has headers?