# Bulk Inserting CSV into Azure SQL with formatting file error

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, bulkinsert

I'm trying to bulk insert data from a csv stored in a blob storage account in an Azure SQL database using a format file.

Here is what I am attempting to run:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.MyTable
FROM 'MyCSV.csv'
WITH(DATA_SOURCE = 'MyBlobStorageAccount'
, FIRSTROW = 2
, CODEPAGE = '65001'
 , FORMATFILE = 'MyFormatFile.xml'
);
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot bulk load because the file "MyFormatFile.xml" could not be opened. Operating system error code (null).

Now, I can successfully load other files from the same storage account that do not use a format file and I can successfully load the contents of `MyFormatFile.xml` using the following, so its not a permissions / credentials issue:

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#data') IS NOT NULL)
    DROP TABLE #data

CREATE TABLE #data
(
    data VARCHAR (MAX)
)

BULK INSERT #data
FROM 'MyFormatFile.xml'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'MyBlobStorageAccount',
      FIRSTROW = 1)
```

What am I doing wrong here? The Microsoft Documentation says that this is supported: [Bulk Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-ver16) there is no need to give file format when trading CSV file jus specify `FORMAT = CSV`

The issue is with your Format file you can simply insert data from csv fil without Format File.

If you still want to use Format File then please check the length of columns and column name that might causing the error.

**Code Example:**

```sql
BULK INSERT rest
FROM 'demo/mysamplecsv.csv'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzurefile',
      FIRSTROW = 2,
      FORMAT = 'CSV');
```

**Execution and Output:**
[image]

Reference: [Examples of bulk access to data in Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-ver16)

also see this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64853761) by Joseph Xu.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need the format file due to quirks in the CSV I'm loading. I also tested inserting the csv locally with the format file and it works successfully. The correct answer is actually in the second link you posted. Where it shows an additional parameter called FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE. This worked successfully.